# UIButton performSelector:withObject:withObject: not making call

Tags: ios

here is my code.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(110, 270, 100, 40);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [button setTitle:@"next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

I want to set button title color through this method
but it doesn't work!

```
    [button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
                 withObject:[UIColor blackColor]
                 withObject:@(UIControlStateNormal)];
```

Do somebody know why it doesn't work???

---

Thank you for all guys's help.
Last night,I found a method to make it works. No matter the parameter is UIControlStateNormal(a special case) or other like UIControlStateHighlighted.
Here is the code:

```
     [button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
                  withObject:[UIColor blueColor]
                  withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)UIControlStateNormal)];
     [button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
                  withObject:[UIColor blackColor]
                  withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)UIControlStateHighlighted)];
     [button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
                  withObject:[UIColor redColor]
                  withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)UIControlStateSelected)];
```

so the question is solved.

---

I found it's useful! So I want to use it do more things,
Here is the code:

```
    [button.layer performSelector:@selector(setMasksToBounds:) withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)YES)];
    [button.layer performSelector:@selector(setCornerRadius:) withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)5)];
    [button.layer performSelector:@selector(setBorderWidth:) withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)5)];
    [button.layer performSelector:@selector(setBorderColor:) withObject:(__bridge id)(__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor greenColor]];
```

when I test,I found it doesn't work again!!! so disappointed :(   . If somebody interested in this question and you can test it.

Comment: are you sure you call performSelector from the main thread?

Comment: Why should call in main thread?

Comment: Does calling setTitleColor:forState: work if called directly?

Comment: @lengahao anything you do with UI should be performed on the main thread. If you are trying to set button's title color on a background thread this will be an undefined behaviour. This is the first cause of the problem that I can think of

Comment: @ Andrey Chernukha I know what you say. The following line of code can run :[button performSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor brownColor]];  I just wonder why this method is working, but the previous method is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you're asking to make the framework make the corresponding call, so you expect

```
[button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
                 withObject:[UIColor blackColor]
                 withObject:@(UIControlStateNormal)];
```

to call

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You are missing one essential thing here: `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` takes two **objects**. You're wrapping the plain integer value (as `UIControlStateNormal` is some int/enum value) within an `NSNumber`. Now that object (or pointer, or address, or whatever you call it) is passed as the second parameter to `setTitleColor:forState:` which is obviously not the value itself, but as that method doesn't know this, it interprets the value as some kind of integer value.

So something like this will be called later:

```
NSNumber *number = ...; // your number object
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:number];
```

As in another answer was said, it probably works by omitting the `@(...)` operator here, so that the value is not wrapped in an `NSNumber`. This is what will happen: `NSControlStateNormal` is defined as `0`. So the compiler will interpret this as `nil`, which is a valid object, or lack of an object. `nil` will then later be reinterpreted as an integer value as an `UIControlState`, so there goes your `0` (== `UIControlStateNormal`) again.

This is a special case that works, because `0` may be treated as `nil`. It will not work (and typically **not even compile**) with any other value, i.e. `UIControlStateFocused`. You will get a 
"Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an rvalue of type '(anonymous enum ...)'" error.

If you insist on going the performSelector: route, you could add a method like this:

```
-(void)setProperties:(NSDictionary *)props onButton:(UIButton *)button {
   UIColor *color = props[@"color"];
   NSNumber *stateWrapper = props[@"state"];
   UIControlState state = (UIControlState)stateWrapper.unsignedIntegerValue;
   [button setTitleColor:color forState:state];
}
```

and use it like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setProperties:onButton:) 
           withObject:@{@"color" : [UIColor blackColor], 
                        @"state" : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:UIControlStateNormal]} 
           withObject:button];
```

It may even be cleaner to wrap the value into `NSValue`, or use a dedicated class for your parameters, etc.

But then, I much prefer the `dispatch_*` mathods anyway, i.e.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:number];
})
```

Or use `dispatch_async` or whatever your intention is at that time.

Comment: I give it a wrong type value, so it doesn't call [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  remove @(), just UIControlStateNormal, it works!!!

Comment: Please see my edited answer. removing @() is just terribly wrong.

Comment: As you say, it is a  special case. How should I do to make it work when I use value like UIControlStateHighlighted , UIControlStateSelected and so on.

Comment: You can't do this without a helper function that does the wrapping/unwrapping. But as the wrongly accepted and upvoted other answer got all the credits, maybe he wants do the work. May it show him why it's an absolute no-no.

Comment: @lengahao I added some solutions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use `[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

And in your case

```
[button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)
             withObject:[UIColor redColor]
             withObject:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Remove `@()` for `UIControlStateNormal`.

Comment: this is obvious. the question is why doesn't work what should be working

Comment: of course I know. I just want to know why this method doesn't work!

Comment: That won't work, as performSelector:: expects objects (which do respond to methods like retain and release). Edit: It **might** work in **this** case as an exception, as UIControlStateNormal == 0 **might** be handled as **nil**. But generally, this won't work as expected.

Comment: This will work.`[button performSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:) withObject:[UIColor redColor] withObject:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: @RahulPatel yes, but it won't work for any other control states.

Comment: @Saad  it works only for UIControlStateNormal, other like UIControlStateHighlighted , UIControlStateSelected ... will cause a error